# Correct solution

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, newtons-method

I am new with R and I need to solve the following nonlinear equation:
 x + 14.67*exp(-x/2) - 2398 with low and hig bounds respectively 2400 and 3000.
I tried "uniroot" and "newton.raphson" functions; I found every time 2398. 
I am not sure that it is correct. any help please.
Thanks in advance.
N.K

Comment: Yes `x = 2398` is a solution to the problem `x + 14.67*exp(-x/2) - 2398 = 0`

Comment: if we replace x by 2398 in the equation we will find 14.67*exp(-2398/2)=0, very strange)

Comment: this is the code: myf <- function(x){x+14.67*exp(-x/2)-2398}   uniroot(myf, c(2000,3002))          $root
[1] 2398

$f.root
[1] 0

$iter
[1] 1

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 604

Comment: It is actually not strange at all, that is the problem you are solving: find `x` such that `x + 14.67*exp(-x/2) - 2398 = 0`. This problem has two solutions `x = 2398` and `x = -10.2017`. In the range `(2400, 3000) ` there are *no* solutions. Unless, of course, this is not the problem you're trying to solve, in which case you should explain what you mean by "...  solve the following ..."

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to solve this problem x= a + (1-F(x))/F'(x)  given that F(x) = 1 - exp(-x^2) and a = 2400. Between the range 2400 and 3002. Many Thanks

Comment: This looks like Newton's method. So, are you trying to find `x` such that `x + 14.67*exp(-x/2) - 2398 = 1` with Newton's method?

Comment: I changed F(x) and F'(x) by their values in the main equation. In the last equation I am tried to solve f(x)=0.